# How do I solve NoMethodError with google_drive gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-drive-api

Im trying to create an web app that reads from a spreadsheet in my google drive. But when Im done with the Oauth2 procedure and wants to list the files I get this Error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `drive' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/google_drive-1.0.0/lib/google_drive/session.rb:101:in `drive'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/google_drive-1.0.0/lib/google_drive/session.rb:149:in `file_by_id'
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/google_drive-1.0.0/lib/google_drive/session.rb:186:in `spreadsheet_by_key'
    from (irb):21
    from /Users/administrator/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Im using Rails 4.2.0 with ruby 2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

`client_or_access_token` argument is `nil`. Look at [this](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/blob/ffac14f97a738f3b1dbda4598c77e7d70823ea5a/lib/google_drive/session.rb#L45) code.